# Any online resources for web control images?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, image, controls, button

I have found plenty of icons online, but have yet to find images for other types of controls except 1-off examples.  For example - buttons, tabs, dropdown menus, sliders, table headers, panel headers, etc.  I've found plenty of tutorials, but our attempts always look bad in comparison (particularly for buttons and tabs).

Are there any free or inexpensive libraries that include this type of thing?  We found some asp.net control libraries that look nice, but paying hundreds just to utilize the images seems like a waste (we are using php and asp.net mvc, so the server controls are worthless for us).

Comment: Why not ask/hire a designer ?

Comment: Because we're not looking for anything fancy.  We just want a standard decent looking set of widgets to select from, and have a very low budget.  Hiring a decent designer at $20-60/hour to create widgets is less cost effective than just buying an ASP.NET user control library, using the images, and throwing out the rest.  I don't see how you're question is any different than saying "Ask a designer to create custom icons for you" ... which seems silly given the # of great free icon sets.  Seems like there must also be control sets/images (maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing though).

Answer (score 2):

[ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) looks like it might be what you're looking for.